# django test a templatetag which uses the request

Tags: django, django-testing

I'm using a custom templatetag to calculate currency values, currency is chosen from a select element. when the user choose the currency he want work with I save the chosen currency in the session and refresh the page.

a templatetag shows the value calculated for the choosen currency.

in any template

```
{% load currency %}
{% set_currency request 156 %}
```

in my_app/templatetags/currency.py

```
from django.conf import settings
from djmoney_rates.utils import convert_money
register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('includes/price.html')
def set_currency(request, price):
    # currency_session could be 'USD', 'EUR' ...
    currency_session = request.session.get(settings.CURRENCY_SESSION_KEY, settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY)
    money = convert_money(price, settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY, currency_session)
    return {'amount': '%d' % money.amount, 'currency': money.currency}
```

includes/price.html is just

```
<span class="amount">{{amount}}</span>
<span class="currency">{{currency}}</span>
```

Now I'm wondering the way to test this templatetag, how to pass the request, and how make session to exists in that request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would only test the function.

```
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory
from django.conf import settings
from my_app.templatetags.currency import set_currency

class SetCurrencyTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.factory = RequestFactory()

    def test_set_currency(self):
        request = self.factory.get('/any/path/really/')
        request.session = {
            settings.CURRENCY_SESSION_KEY: settings.DEFAULT_CURRENCY
        }

        response = set_currency(request, 156)

        self.assertEqual(response['amount'], 42)
        self.assertEqual(response['currency'], 'BTC')
```

I'd also consider setting `request.session` without using `settings`, but that depends on your application.